# foreach loop where order needs to be specific

Tags: c#, sorting, razor, foreach, element

I am trying to go through an array of shipping methods, and then set them in a table as an option. The problem is that my shipping methods are scrambled, and we don't want to rearrange it in our database. That means I need to go through all elements, but in the order of the following shipmethodIDs: 11, 13, 12.

Following is the code snippet:

```
@foreach (var shippingMethod in availableShippingMethods)
{
    bool chosen = false;
    if (choosenShippingMethod != null)
    {
        if (choosenShippingMethod.Id == shippingMethod.Id)
        {
            chosen = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        chosen = counter == availableShippingMethods.Count();
    }
    <td>
        ... some html here ...
    </td>
}
```

Comment: if _availableShippingMethods_ is the model received by the page then change it at Controller level adding a property order where you set the order you like for the elements and order them with an OrderBy before returning the view with the model

Comment: I'm not 100% if this will work as i only really touch `PHP`, i Imagine you would be able to sort the array by the shipmethodID.

Comment: `availableShippingMethods.OrderBy(....)` ?  Define the sort logic in the `OrderBy` predicate.  How do you define your sort logic?  That is, when looking at your data, how do you know what order it *should* be?

Comment: Is there any other column you can use to sort your elements ? What exactly is the criteria you want to use ?

Answer (score 3):

Create a column in your database table called `sorting_order`, sort on that column from your query or a view and you are done. Flexible, reusable, check.

Never rely on IDs never changing, or other weird logic. You can't maintain such software.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I would never do this normally, but we are switching to a new platform soon, so this will all be scrapped. I'll look into a new column in the database.

Comment: So if somewhere else you want to sort the table on another criteria you'll add a `sorting_order2` column, then a `sorting_order3` column ? Meh, before this, you should consider asking what is your sorting criteria and if it can be resolved using existing columns...

Comment: Usually the shipping method sorting order depends on the sales department maximizing their profit. I would expect it to either sort on the an existing column, like name (still an available option) or an artificial, manual sorting order (this fixes that problem). I don't expect any more sorting orders on such table. @Rafalon

Comment: (And this solution is better than adding it somewhere in a code block in your view or controller.)

Comment: Well, then in code-behind you could order it depending on a `Count` of the sales using each shipping method, and it will update automatically, and no need for extra column, and no need for extra statistics and extra updates in database

Comment: I wouldn't do a count on ALL sales orders just to get the sorting order for the shipping method... @Rafalon

Comment: Then you could do a count on say last month's sales or whatever. Count isn't that time-eating nowadays